# Imagemagick cannot use identify on remote image if it contains a port number

Tags: php, regex, url, imagemagick, port

I am having trouble using exec identify on a remote image with imagemagick if the url contains a port number. So the url appears like this: `http://isite.com:81/image.jpg`  If I remove the :81 it works. What can I do? Either fixing this issue with imagemagick or removing the port number is fine. I tried using PHP's parse_url function to remove the port, however I cannot reconstruct the url afterwards because http_build_url() function is not available on my server and I cannot install it. The above URL is an example. Here is the original URL `http://img.wallpaperstock.net:81/jeep-in-desert-wallpapers_11419_1600x1200.jpg`

Comment: Stripping the port will break most URLs. It is not a solution to the problem. Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing any code nor telling what exactly doesn't work, but if you are using `exec`, chances are that you simply need to escape the parameter before you pass it to ImageMagick.

If you're getting the URLs from the outside, you **need** to do this anyway for security reasons!

```
$ip = "http://isite.com:81/image.jpg";

$ip_safe = escapeshellarg($ip);

exec("identify $ip_safe");
```

Comment: +1 for introducing escapehellarg to me and I am not sure if the OP will ever tell us if your answer solved his problem.

Comment: This did not fix the problem, but thanks for the security tip.

Comment: @Mike can you show the exact code you are using? If the call doesn't work when it has a port number in it, you should be getting error messages back.

Answer (score -1):

The required regexp would be

```
preg_replace('/(?<=[^:]):\d+\//i', '/', 'http://isite.com:81/image.jpg');
```

Comment: -1: Stripping the port from the URL does not solve the OP's problem, it just breaks the URL.

Comment: @Pekka why? He has written **If I remove the :81 it works.**. So, where is the problem?

Comment: @stema maybe it happens to fix the problem on a specific server that serves the same content on two different ports. But how many servers do you know that do that? Usually, by removing the port, you break the URL, plain and simple. You're empowering an incorrect assumption on the OP's end instead of correcting it

Comment: The problem was stated rather clearly **Either fixing this issue with imagemagick or removing the port number is fine.** So, if somebody has asked you whether 3+3=6 what would you say? Does it depend on the group/field you are considering or would you just say **YES**?

Comment: Removing the port number from the URL did in fact load the remote image correctly within imagemagick, but I have to manually remove the port...